# Firefox experiences a sec_error_unknown_issuer error for every HTTPS connection

Tags: windows-7, firefox, certificate, https

When I attempt to connect to any site that uses an HTTPS connection (e.g. https://www.google.com), I get a 'This Connection is Untrusted' error.  I'm using FF 42.0.

I followed the instructions in the `The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown` section of the ["This Connection is Untrusted" error message appears - What to do](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-untrusted-error-message) page--essentially deleting the `cert8.db` file located in my Firefox profile folder (when FF was closed, BTW).

I restarted FF, but the problem persists.

Chrome (46.0.2490.86 m) and IE (10.0.9200.17519CO) work as expected.

What am I missing?

** edit **

For some reason, the '' option is presented for https://www.google.com, so I'm posting the certificate for https://www.yahoo.com instead (same error).

General:

[image: general tab]

Details:

[image: details tab]

Comment: Are you able to post the details of the certificate firefox is trying to load?  On the page that says 'This connection is untrusted', click on 'I understand the risks' and the 'add exception' (DO NOT ACTUALLY ADD THE EXCEPTION).  One the popup screen shows you can view the certificate before adding the exception. It will show the certificate chain and details on what certificate is loading.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant, but I'm having similar issues with RubyGems.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some bad certificates in your Firefox store. Here is the certificates from yahoo.com and google.com for my browser.  You'll see that they are from a trusted certificate authority -- VeriSign and GeoTrust, where yours is from SHC Issuing CA.

The only other thing that might be happening is SSL inspection if your computer is on a corporate network and they have some kind of appliance that does SSL Inspection.  But this is unlikely since it works fine with IE and Chrome.

**Yahoo Certificate**

[image]

**Google Certificate**

[image]

Have a look at this article from Firefox on how to fix the issue.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/secure-connection-failed-error-message

I would be trying to delete the cert8.db file:

```
The file cert8.db in your profile folder may have become corrupted. Delete this file while Firefox is closed.

Open your profile folder:

Click the menu button, click help and select Troubleshooting Information. The Troubleshooting Information tab will open.
Under the Application Basics section, click on Show Folder. A window with your profile files will open.
Note: If you are unable to open or use Firefox, follow the instructions in Finding your profile without opening Firefox.

Click the menu button and then click Exit.
Click on the file named cert8.db.
Press Delete.
Restart Firefox.
cert8.db will be recreated when you restart Firefox. This is normal.
```

Failing that I would be uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox.

Also do a virus scan to check if something bad has infected your browser, just for piece of mind.

Comment: I have already removed the cert8.db file and restarted.  I've also tried removing FF and all of its components.  Same results.  I am on a corporate network.

Comment: If you are on a corporate network I would be asking your IT department.  They probably have per-installed, or pushed out certificates for Chrome and IE but not FireFox.  I know from experience that it is a lot easier to manage these settings for Chrome and IE, where FireFox can be more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it by changing connection settings in option->advanced->network->settings->auto-detect,perhaps it will work for you.

Comment: Why will that work in this instance? The browser will still be using the locally installed certificates

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.